# Image not loading from fetched url

Tags: javascript

I am fetching a image url from a placeid of a roblox game via noblox.js the url response is something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "targetId": 4111023553,
            "state": "Completed",
            "imageUrl": "https://tr.rbxcdn.com/6c6e12c567342835b16e787d9ea60467/50/50/Image/Png",
            "version": null
        }
    ]
}
```

The `img.src` when I try to set the image to the `imageUrl` from the fetched data it doesn't properly display the `imageUrl` image it just displays a placeholder image. Note this is an electron app. It could be a fetching error. However, I use this same bit of code in a different part of my code and works perfectally normal it only fails here.

```
var imageUrl

function GetGameIcon(placeid) {
    var gameInfo = `https://thumbnails.roblox.com/v1/places/gameicons?placeIds=${placeid}&returnPolicy=PlaceHolder&size=50x50&format=Png&isCircular=false`
    fetch(gameInfo).then(responce => responce.json()).then(data => {
         imageUrl = data.data[0].imageUrl
         imageUrl = imageUrl.replace("50/50", "20/20")

         const img = document.querySelector('img')
         img.src = imageUrl
   })
}

function Run() {
   document.getElementById("gamename").innerHTML = game
   GetGameIcon(placeid)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Run function is executed only after the DOM content has fully loaded.

```
function Run() {
        // Make sure to run after the DOM is fully loaded
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            document.getElementById("gamename").innerHTML = game;
            GetGameIcon(placeid);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare img variable from const to var.

const img = document.querySelector('img')

> var img = document.querySelector('img')

Comment: And why is that ? They do not reassign the `img` variable, why would they use `var` ? And even if they did, it should be `let`, not `var`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).